# Tokens or token types missing name property

Tags: 7, tokens

I am having issues in tokens, sometimes they stop working and are not available for use. When I browse the tokens only these are available.

> [image]

After I check the status report, I can see the following message.

> [image]

Tokens start working automatically, but I am not able to find out why they are not working and why they start working on their own.

I tried clearing the cache many times, but it doesn't help.

#### Note

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240968/tokens-or-token-types-missing-name-property) question being asked by me, but I am posting here as it is Drupal specific and I am not able to find the working solution for this.

Comment: When it happens that tokens stop working, are you able to look at the Drupal watchdog log admin/reports/dblog and are there any php or other non-user errors?

Comment: No errors in drupal watchdog log.

Comment: Strange... Do you have any features installed and if yes, do any have token module as dependency? Any modules that depend on token module?